Inconsistent Button Visibility Behavior with NavigationMixin
I created a button in a custom object, with the Action Type set to Flow.
Then, I configured the action's visibility in the lightning page layout based on certain conditions.
When the conditions are met, I can see the button as expected.
Pressing the button initiates a screen flow that calls an LWC.
After some logic in an Apex class, it redirects to the record page using the following code:
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__recordPage',
    attributes: {
        recordId: this.recordId,
        actionName: 'view'
    }
});

After the Apex class saves the data and returns a result to the LWC, it initiates the redirection as described above.
However, on the record page, sometimes the button is still there, and sometimes it's not, even though the conditions are no longer met.
After refreshing the page (F5), the button doesn't appear again.
When I'm not using NavigationMixin and instead use window.location.href:
    let redirectURL = 'https://' + window.location.hostname + '/lightning/r/' + this.recordId+ '/view';
   window.location.href = redirectURL;

this issue doesn't occur. However, I prefer to use NavigationMixin due to potential Salesforce URL-related issues.
Is there an option to force a hard reload when navigating to the page using NavigationMixin?
Thank you!

You should be able to fix this by calling notifyRecordUpdateAvailable before navigating.
await notifyRecordUpdateAvailable([{ recordId: this.recordId }]);
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__recordPage',
    attributes: {
        recordId: this.recordId,
        actionName: 'view'
    }
});

This gives Lightning Data Service a chance to update the record in the cache after Apex has modified it.

Thank you! thats great!
